# How to use a function as a string while using matching pattern

Tags: bash, function, shell

I want to make use of functions to get the full path and directory name of a script.
For this I made two functions :

```
function _jb-get-script-path ()
{
    #returns full path to current working directory 
    # + path to the script + name of the script file
    return $PWD/${0#./*}
}

function _jb-get-script-dirname ()
{
    return ${(_jb-get-script-path)##*/}
}
```

as $(_jb-get-script-path) should be replaced by the result of the function called.
However, I get an error: `${(_jb-get-script-path)##*/}: bad substitution`

therefore i tried another way :

```
function _jb-get-script-path ()
{
    return $PWD/${0#./*}
}

function _jb-get-script-dirname ()
{
    local temp=$(_jb-get-script-path);
    return ${temp##*/}
}
```

but in this case, the first functions causes an error : `numeric argument required`. I tried to run `local temp=$(_jb-get-script-path $0)` in case the $0 wasn't provided through function call (or i don't really know why) but it didn't change anything

I don't want to copy the content of the second fonction as i don't want to replicate code for no good reason.
If you know why those errors happen, I really would like to know why, and of course, if you have a better solution, i'd gladely hear it. But I'm really interessed in the resolution of this problem.

Comment: Any reason not to use `basename` and `dirname`?

Comment: Not really, but now i would like to understand what really happened here.

Comment: Also, in bash functions do not return a value, they return an exit status, which should be between 0 and 255.

Comment: indeed. I close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `echo` instead of return which is used for returning a numeric status:

```
_jb-get-script-path() {
    #returns full path to current working directory
    # + path to the script + name of the script file
    echo "$PWD/${0#./*}"
}

_jb-get-script-dirname() {
    local p="$(_jb-get-script-path)"
    echo "${p##*/}"
}

_jb-get-script-dirname
```